# Kivy -- scroll view not working. And and how add chat users on side pane

Tags: python, kivy

I'm trying to do write a chat application with an interface that has users names on the side pane that's scrollable.

I have 2 questions:

1- This code is not scrolling, please let me know what I'm doing wrong:

```
stacklayout2 = StackLayout(orientation='lr-tb',)
## Scrollview layout
scroll_layout = GridLayout(cols=1, 
                           spacing=20,
                           size_hint_y=None
                           )
scroll_layout.bind(minimum_height=layout.setter('height'))

for i in range(10):
    scroll_layout.add_widget(ToggleButton(text=str(i), 
                                          size_hint_y=None, 
                                          height=40
                                          )
                            )


scrollview = ScrollView(size_hint=(.3,.5), do_scroll_x=False)
scrollview.add_widget(scroll_layout)


stacklayout2.add_widget(scrollview)
stacklayout2.add_widget(Button(text='Send',size_hint=(.2,.2)))

s2.add_widget(stacklayout2)
```

2- Is it the best way to put (clickable/selectable) users on the side pane, I'm doing it right?

Comment: why was "size_hint_y=None" commented? it should be activated, or your gridlayout will take exactly 100% of the height and you won't have anything to scroll…, also, didn't you mean "scroll_layout.setter('height')"?

Comment: It doesn't work with or without "size_hint_y=None" part, so, I thought to take it off until I find the real reason behind the non-scrolling pane -- anyway, I'll remove the comment and update the post. I'm not sure what you mean by your question, are you referring to my second question in the main post?

Comment: Binding of the scroll_layout on 7th row should refer to the scroll_layout: scroll_layout.bind(minimum_height=scroll_layout.setter('height'))

Comment: Thanks dude, this was really the problem.

Comment: @tshirtman you said it first, but I didn't get it, so please add your comment as an answer check-mark it.

Comment: also guys I need an answer to my second question, is it the best way to make a scrollable pane of users, by making them clickable buttons or toggle buttons, I'm not sure what is the best approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Resubmitting as answer as requested :)

the error is on the binding,

```
scroll_layout.bind(minimum_height=scroll_layout.setter('height'))
```

is what you need, so scrool_layout height is updated when it minimum_heigh is updated.

Comment: Then you got the answer checked, and +1 candy :)

Comment: btw, in the non-multiline textinput, I'm using this `on_text_validate`, I went to documentation and I found this line: `Fired only in multiline=False mode, when the user hits ‘enter’. This will also unfocus the textinput.`, how can I keep the focus on the field?

Comment: I would set `your_input.focus=True` again in your binding to on_text_validate. :)