# Kivy ScrollView of Label won't scroll

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I have a Label inside a ScrollView, hoping that that when the (multiline) text takes up too many lines, the user can scroll up & down, and when the lines are too long, the user can scroll left & right.  And I can't get it to scroll.  Here's the relevant part of my Builder string:

```
ScrollView:
    id: scrollLayout
    size_hint_y: 0.9
    Label:
        id: sortFilesDisplay
        size_hint_y: 0.9
        text: 'Drag\\n in\\n files\\n to\\n be\\n sorted\\n yea\\n go\\n now\\n testing\\n please\\n work\\n now\\help'
```

I've read the [Kivy docs on ScrollView](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.scrollview.html), that say I need to specify one of the size_hints to enable scrolling.  I've readseveral SO posts about getting ScrollView to work:

- [Kivy ScrollView - Not Scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32445341/kivy-scrollview-not-scrolling)
- [kivy scrollview is not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44610516/kivy-scrollview-is-not-working)
- [kivy Scrollview can't Scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43111800/kivy-scrollview-cant-scroll)
- [ScrollView widget not scolling in kivy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19030727/scrollview-widget-not-scolling-in-kivy)
- [Kivy -- scroll view not working. And and how add chat users on side pane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14542189/kivy-scroll-view-not-working-and-and-how-add-chat-users-on-side-pane)
- [Kivy - My ScrollView doesn't scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39489980/kivy-my-scrollview-doesnt-scroll)

but they all involve embedding some kind of Layout (e.g. GridLayout), abut I'm not embedding a layout, just one Label. I've tried setting minimum_height to various things I saw in those posts, but still no effect.

Those two size_hint_y's are in there just to try to do as directed; I don't need them.  Also tried setting them to None.

Any ideas?

Also, that static string for text isn't what I ultimately want. I want the Label to remain scrollable when the string changes (when users drop in a new list of files), but I thought perhaps the 'dynamic' action was a problem, so for now I 'retreated' to trying a static string.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In order for  the `Label` to be scrollable it should be bigger than `ScrollView` widget, so you need to set `size_hint` to `None` and bind label size to text size. For example:

**test.kv:**

```
ScrollView:
    Label:
        id: sortFilesDisplay
        size_hint: None, None     # <<<<<<<<<<
        size: self.texture_size   # <<<<<<<<<<
        text: "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit,\n sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.\n\n" * 20
```

**main.kv**

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.config import Config
Config.set('graphics', 'width', '300')
Config.set('graphics', 'height', '200')


class TestApp(App):
    pass


if __name__ == '__main__':
    TestApp().run()
```

Comment: Oh! It's the *Label size* that needed the size_hint set to None.  I was trying to do that to the ScrollIView.  Great!  Thanks!